# AWS EC2 AMI for running Docker images

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I'm looking to automate the provisioning of an EC2 instance that will run docker and a specific container by default when the machine comes up. I have been using Amazon's ECS AMI, but am wondering if there's a better one out there that has Docker pre-installed. Does anyone have experience using another AMI from the marketplace?

Comment: did you find a matching aws ami optimized for docker? Currently I'm looking for a solution. The only one provided on the aws ami marketplace does not match my requirements as it is optimized for aws ecs.

Comment: I was able to use the ecs optimized AMI for my use case.

Answer (score 4):

the easiest option is passing the script via User data(other wise just run it manually when connecting to the instance) section while creating a new EC2 machine.

```
yum update -y
amazon-linux-extras install docker
service docker start
usermod -a -G docker ec2-user
chkconfig docker on
```

just as a note this refer to the amazon linux AMI(default), just check for the instruction of your AMI and change accordingly

Comment: I had to use sudo but this worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled across this question while researching the same question. I haven't found any existing AMIs that come pre-configured with Docker, although I'm sure. A deeper search will find one. However, you can also create your own AMI. It isn't at all difficult and only takes a few minutes.

[AWS AMI Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/tkv-create-ami-from-instance.html)

In short: launch an EC2 instance with your favorite flavor of Linux. Install and configure your base Jenkins, and then follow these pretty simple directions to create a custom AMI.

Answer (score 1):

When choosing an AMI at instance launch, searching "docker" or "deep learning" will turn up deep learning AMIs that come with Docker installed.